# Integrating Flex Publisher Licensing into an application

Tags: apache-flex, licensing, publishing, flexlm

A friend of mine asked me to take a look at using Flex Licensing to protect the distribution of her software.  I've spent a bit of time going through the flexera website to see what information I could glean, but I find nothing that tells me how one actually connects their software to the licensing system.  Is it an API that allows me to build the functionality into an application?  Is it something else?  I decided to not put too much time into getting frustrated before asking here if anyone had any experience with this or similar licensing systems.

Regards and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, there is an API.

You can request a trial of their [FlexNet Publisher Software](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/ECM-EVAL-FlexNet-Publisher) to see if it is something you would like to work with.  However, I would recommend you contact them to see if their pricing model would fit into your friend's development budget.